# ¿Cómo exportar e imprimir registros en un DataTable?

Tags: datatable

Tengo una cuestión sobre cómo exportar o imprimir un campo de DataTable. ¿existe alguna función de este mismo?

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato, es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Creo que requieres poner alguna imagen si no en el mismo data table tiene buscar y pues mandas a imprimir lo que tienes en pantalla !

Comment: `$("table tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text()` tendrías el dato de la fila 1 columna 1

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
} );
```

Con esto le pones un evento onClick a cada fila de la tabla

Es como decir a la tabla #example en su elemento tbody cuando le den click a un elemento tr ejecuta console.log( table.row( this ).data() );

o puedes usar

```
$("table tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text()
```

si solo quieres un campo

Comment: voy a implementarlo para ver como funciona

Comment: Aver si entendi con esta funcion agrego un boton el cual manda a llamar a la variable que se va a declarar ?

Comment: Le estas poniendo un evento onClick a cada fila de la tabla.

Comment: al momento de ponerlo no me muestra los campos solo aparesen los titulos de cada columna pero ningun campo a que se puede dever eso ?